# Resultado estranho no to.monthly (pacote quantmod) série cortada

Tags: r

Problema com meu to.monthly. 
Ele corta minha série de dados, não sei porque.

```
####install.packages("quantmod")
library(quantmod)
####install.packages("PerformanceAnalytics")
library(PerformanceAnalytics)
####install.packages("zoo")
library(zoo)

####Definindo diretório principal
setDefaults(getSymbols, src='google')

StartDate = as.Date("2004-01-01") ####data de começo
EndDate = as.Date("2017-01-01") ####data de término


ibovespa <- getSymbols('IBOV', from=StartDate, to=EndDate, auto.assign = F)
ibovespa_monthly <- to.monthly(ibovespa) #->->->->->->->->->problem#####
colnames(ibovespa_monthly) <- c("Open", "High", "Low", "Close","Volume")
ibovespa_return <- (Return.calculate(ibovespa_monthly$Close)[-1,])*100
plot.zoo(ibovespa_return, xlab="Mês", ylab = "Porcentagem")

table.CalendarReturns(ibovespa_return)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note que a partir de 2013-06-27, a coluna `ibovespa$IBOV.Volume` possui apenas `NA`. A função `to.monthly` não é capaz, até onde sei, de lidar com esta falta de informação.

Perceba que se eu trocar de ativo, este erro deixa de ocorrer:

```
petr4         <- getSymbols('petr4', from=StartDate, to=EndDate, auto.assign = F)
petr4_monthly <- to.monthly(petr4)
petr4_monthly
```

Entendo pouco do mercado de ações, mas acho que não faz sentido registrar o volume do índice Bovespa como um todo. Faz sentido pensar no volume de negociações de um papel em particular, seja ele VALE5, ITUB4 ou PETR4, como no exemplo. Mas da Bovespa como um todo acho que não faz sentido. Eu, pelo menos, nunca vi.

Portanto, o que sugiro é remover a coluna 5 do objeto `bovespa` para que os outros resultados sejam calculados corretamente.

```
ibovespa         <- getSymbols('IBOV', from=StartDate, to=EndDate, auto.assign = F)
ibovespa         <- ibovespa[, -5]
ibovespa_monthly <- to.monthly(ibovespa)
```

Comment: Eu não havia me dado conta, mas havia NA values no meu arquivo.
Quando eu apliacva a função monthly ele só calculava até o valor NA.

Obrigado, Marcos!!!

Comment: Fico feliz em saber que consegui te ajudar. Por favor, aceite a minha resposta para que, no futuro, outras pessoas possam consultá-la e resolver este mesmo problema, caso ele surja.